# Ajax Inquiry POST

Tags: ajax, post, get, roblox

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=148530",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var gg = data
    function Post(){
      $.get(url,function(Data){
        var VS = Data.match(/id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+)"/)[1]
        var EV = Data.match(/id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+)"/)[1]
        $.post(url,{
          "__VIEWSTATE" : VS,
          "__EVENTVALIDATION" : EV,
          "__EVENTTARGET" : "ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$GroupMemberAdminPane$dlMembers_Footer$ctl02$ctl00",
          "__EVENTARGUMENT" : 'Click',
        })
      })
    }
    Post()
  }
})
```

I'm trying to get it to log it the other way around, so the `$.post` request would show the data from that page (the ranks I'm trying to get).

Help please? I really need answers as fast as possible.

Comment: Your code is not clear to me and also is not clear what you need, if you've any errors, more info will be helpful in order to help

Comment: I just want it to log the data of the page that it is supposed to click. The __EVENTTARGET button is what its supposed to click and I want it to log the data of that page.

Comment: What is `url`? And why don't you use `gg` for anything?

Comment: I'm very new to Ajax. I thought url was the URL that was sent with the ajax request. I forgot I had gg in there, I need to get rid of it.

Comment: I've rolled back your question edit. Please don't replace your own code with that from my answer. That's a *substantial* change to your question - and it's spectacularly bad style, too. You are here to *learn stuff yourself*, not to re-post other people's code until someone writes the lines you need. Seriously, that's offensive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
function postback(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    return function (html) {
        var $html = $("<div>").append(html);

        $.post(this.url, {
            __VIEWSTATE: $html.find("#__VIEWSTATE").val(),
            __EVENTVALIDATION: $html.find("#__EVENTVALIDATION").val(),
            __EVENTTARGET: eventTarget,
            __EVENTARGUMENT: eventArgument
        });
    };
}

var url = "http://www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=148530",
    target = "ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$GroupMemberAdminPane$dlMembers_Footer$ctl02$ctl00";

$.get(url).done(postback(target, "Click"));
```

What's going on here:

The function `postback()` creates another function and returns it. *That* function accepts an HTML string as its argument, parses out *viewstate* and *eventvalidation* and sends a webforms-compatible postback to a pre-determined target control. In effect it encapsulates the action of sending a webforms event.

The last line does the actual work: It GETs `url` and calls `postback()` (which produces the matching Ajax success callback function). Once the Ajax request returns successfully, the `.done()` callback is called which *then* triggers a click event on the control.

Notes:

- Trying to fetch URLs from a different domain than the one the script runs on will fail (see same-origin policy).
- Parsing HTML with regular expressions is strongly discouraged. As you can see, with something as powerful as jQuery doing it correctly is even easier to read.
- You probably should include a sanity check to see if the target control even exists in the page before you post the event. (`if ($html.find("#" + eventTarget).length) ...`)
- Semicolons. Use them.

Recommended reading:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR
- Any tutorial on JavaScript promises.

Comment: Like that, correct.

I just need it to output the names too, so how would I fix this?

Comment: What names? Where do you want to output them to?

Comment: You're not really asking me to add a line with `console.log()` to my code, are you?